# Do you know the formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems, angle

I have three data:

- coordinates $(x,y)$
- angle in degrees ($\gamma^\circ$)
- distance in meters (m)

How should I calculate in general a new position $(a_1,b_1)$?

> For example, assume the following initial data:
>
> - Initial coordinates $(a_0, b_0)=(100,100)$,
> - angle = $30^\circ$,
> - distance $2$ m.
>
> What is the result (i.e. my new position $(a_1,b_1)$?

Sorry for formulation of this topic and explanation of my problem, but I really need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working in terms of vectors: assuming $\theta$ is taken from the positive real axis, then the resultant coordinates would be

$$(100, 100) + (r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta) = (100 + r\sin\theta, 100 + r\cos\theta)$$

where $r$ is said distance.